# What class implements the spring framework Autowired

Tags: spring

I downloaded [the spring-framework project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework), because I want to see how `@Autowired` is implemented.

So, I got to [this file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8aa6e5bfea2c7314deaa1b432554e9e914b09ee7/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.java), which is an interface.

But when I want in Intellij to go to its implementation, no implementations are found.

[image]

So is this interface not implemented?

Then where is the code for `@Autowired`?

Comment: Look up how spring processes annotations. The annotation itself won’t tell you anything. See https://dzone.com/articles/spring-annotation-processing-how-it-works

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not an `interface` it is actually an `annotation`. 
In java `@inteface` is used to create an `annotation`.

Once the annotation is created, you can use that annotation on fields, classes, methods (based on what is specified in @Target of the annotation definition.

Spring does package scanning and finds all the things which are using a particular annotation and does the required processing.

Use [this](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-annotations-in-java) article to undestand more in How an annotation is created, used and the how the annotation processor finds and processes the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` doesn't really have much code, so to speak. It's just an annotation which is a Java type of interface that provides instructions to other parts of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` is only an annotation or you can say a "marker". Spring use [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html) to identify annotation and do something about that annotated thing. For example with `@Autowired`, when spring found it, spring will inject the annotated property with eligible bean.